# Calculate maximum flow efficiently after adding a new edge in Ford Fulkerson algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, ford-fulkerson

Suppose that a maximum ﬂow for G has been computed using Ford-Fulkerson, and a new edge with unit capacity is added to E. How the maximum ﬂow can be efﬁciently updated. (t is not the value of the ﬂow that must be updated, but the ﬂow itself.

Comment: Try to find an augmenting path that uses the new edge. You will need linear time to do it (one DFS)

Comment: Can you show us the code written till now to calculate the max flow of an initial graph without considering the new edge that gets added??

Comment: i have not written any code so far just want ti make it clear theoretically. But I am using Ford Fulkerson algorithm ....

Comment: Although Niklas B.'s comment basically is the solution, one could also try to maintain the minimum cut along the calculation. If the added edge is not in the cut, the maximum flow has not changed.

Comment: alright... i am getting the point. can you please explain what is mean by the term   "undone" here  in the following link,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455970/update-maximum-flow-after-adding-an-edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let *G'* be the graph with the new edge *e* added to *G*. Note that we retain the capacity and flow for the remaining edges.

Now find an augmenting path *p* in *G'*.

If *p* exists, then update the flow along that path in *G'* by 1. Otherwise, the flow remains the same.

This gives the final flow values. This is correct because if *p* exists, then it passes through *e*. Hence, the flow update along *p* is exactly by 1. Since Folk-Fulkerson algorithm increases the flow in integral steps, there is no augmenting path in *G'* after this update.

If *p* doesn't exist, then by the mincut-maxflow argument, this is the maximum flow as the mincut is 0.